# Choose first device from paired devices

Tags: android

How to choose first device in `pairedDevices` list without using `for` loop?

Do they number from 0 like in usual array or from 1?

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set` is an unordered `Collection`, the items cannot be accessed by index.

The closest thing you can do is something like this:

```
BluetoothDevice firstDevice = pairedDevices.iterator().next();
```